# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_loadWeak

Tags: ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking, ios4

Im currently working on an iPad application that is `ARC` enabled. The application works fine on iOS versions 5.0 , 5.1 and 6.0 but crashes with the error 
 on iOS 4.3 ..

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_loadWeak

I thought it could be something related to `AFNetworking` as the crash happens just after a network request so I downgraded my version to 0.10.1.2 but still I seem to get the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 4 does not fully support ARC; It supports "ARCLite". In this case, Zeroing Weak References are not available in iOS 4.3.

So the immediate solutions are:

- avoid `__weak` and its relatives
- or drop iOS4.3
- or move the relevant bits of your implementation over to MRC

---

Reference: [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html)

Comment: Thank you , this was exactly the problem. I solved it by changing the deployment target of a static library that I used to 4.3.